Haystack inmemorydocumentstore can store only 10 documents
everyone i have been using haystack inmemorydocumentstore with overwrite policy. I wanted to store for 5k documents as vector db using inmemorydocumentstore of haystack.
But i came to know that it stores only 10documents. Is this normal?
Should i use other db to store for than 10 documents
Also, if those 5k documents are bit similar is there a way to assign id for each documents. I felt like the overwrite policy is also affecting.
I tried using haystack in memory document store but it only stores 10 documents as vector.

Hello! I'm from the Haystack team...
InMemoryDocumentStore is meant for experimentation but it can definitely store more than 10 documents (even more than 10K :-)). So you may be doing something wrong. Please add a reproducible example to this question. You can also join Discord (https://discord.com/invite/VBpFzsgRVF) or ask the question (with a reproducible example) on Github Discussions (https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/discussions).

Kind of solved the problem with qdrant db setting the embedding dim more than the document provided.
inmemorydocumentstore did store more document but it seems to have a limitation when similar docs are provided in large number, they kind of overwrite it.
